# CSS3 animation doesn't work is display property is set to inline

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I've been playing with this demo : http://ademilter.com/lab/liffect/  (choose: zoomIn)

```
ul[data-liffect="zoomIn"] li {
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  -webkit-animation: zoomIn 600ms ease both;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  -moz-animation: zoomIn 600ms ease both;
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  -o-animation: zoomIn 600ms ease both;
  -o-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation: zoomIn 600ms ease both;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

Then I've tried to reproduce that effect on my own, and I've found out that it doesn't work if the list item property is set to `inline` as opposed to `inline-block`.

If display property is `inline` it only does the fade in.

Interesting this is that if you look at the original site with development panel, list items in the demo don't have the display property set to `inline-block`.

So I have to make my list items `inline-block`, but that gives me margins on the elements.

Is there any way around this?

I've singled out the animation effect [here](http://jsfiddle.net/iki_xx/mDYDb/).

Can you animate the scale of an element if that element has a display property set to `inline`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way around it. You can remove the space that you get using `inline-block` by typing the elements without spaces.

Something like this:

```
<ul data-liffect="zoomIn"><li><img src="http://cambelt.co/100x100"></li><li><img src="http://cambelt.co/100x100"></li><li><img src="http://cambelt.co/100x100"></li><li><img src="http://cambelt.co/100x100"></li><li><img src="http://cambelt.co/100x100"></li><li><img src="http://cambelt.co/100x100"></li></ul>​
```

The reason for this is because the space you are seing isn't actually a `margin`, it's a space character just like you would get between typed words. Inline-blocks render these the same way. Another way around it could be to use the `float` property instead.

Here's a [demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/mDYDb/3/)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Another way to remove the space between inline-block element is to declare font-size:0 on the parent element.

Comment: OK, but please mark the answer as correct, provided that it helped you, or let me know if I should clarify my answer.